# React Build Locally different from Build from CI/CD

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I started noticing something pretty strange with my React application. I have a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline that installs my dependencies, runs my tests, lints, builds the production build, and deploys it to the cloud.

I recently added a new feature to my app and the Jenkins pipeline worked well. However, one thing I noticed when it got deployed was that a pre-existing tool on my app crashed when I didn't modify any of that code.

Unsure why this happened, I tried to manually build it locally and manualyl deploy it to the cloud and surprisingly, the issue was fixed! I'm not sure why it was fixed though..

This may be a very dumb question but... is it possible for a React build based on what platform is it built on (local, CI/CD, etc) to show different behavior in the application?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you used the exact commands manually that are used on CI/CD? Could it be that when you ran it manually you did not use [lock file](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile)?

Comment: @HMR, I don't use the same exact commands actually. Locally, I use `yarn`, but on my Jenkins pipeline, I use `npm` due to having problems getting `yarn` on Jenkins. Do you think this could be the reason why? If so, would like to learn more why this would cause problems.